# Why boto enforces that s3 bucket must be lower case?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

It seems that boto will check the s3 bucket name to be lowercase, and throw exception if not. But in AWS console, I can create a S3 bucket name with uppercase, then why boto does not want to support uppercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered [on their issues page](https://code.google.com/p/boto/issues/detail?id=371).